# How to create a model with only fields that have data

Tags: django

Suppose I have the following fields

```
name = ...
date_of_birth = ...
```

date_of_birth is optional and can be 'None'

Code like:

```
Person = Person(name=name, date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
```

Gives me validation errors if `date_of_birth` is null.  Is there a way to construct a Person without `date_of_birth` if it has a null value?

Comment: Put `null=True` in the field definition.

Comment: `null=True` is not enough, as `null` just allows to store `null` in database. To permit empty values in forms, it is needed to set also `blank=True`. Look [null docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare date_of_birth field with `null=True` option, e.g.

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='someverbosename', null=True)
```

This makes a field possible to take null value.